# How can I add a vertical space in 'Terminal' after each command?

Tags: macos, terminal

I've just started using Terminal (the CLI for Mac OS X).

When I run a command, get some information back, run another command, get more info etc., it is hard (on the eyes) to find a certain point on the screen (e.g. the output for the command before last).

Is there a way of adding a vertical empty space to the end of each output/ after each command is run that has no output?

Comment: Hitting enter / return on a blank prompt will give you a blank line. You can also redirect output to a text file with something like `command > outputfile.txt` i.e. `ls > dirinfo.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I press 'enter' I don't get an empty line though, I get a line with my current working directory on it. Could the above be done with a script?

Answer (score 6):

Each new command that you enter is preceded by a "prompt", and these can be customized (though the exact *way* to customize depends on the shell). Since you mention Mac OS X I'm assuming you are using the default `bash` shell, in which case the absolute simplest way to add a blank line is like this: `PROMPT_COMMAND=echo`. You can run that command to try it out, or add it to a startup file (like `.profile` in your home folder) to have it done automatically each time.

Comment: Or change the prompt; `PS1=$'\n'"$PS1"`

Comment: @tripleee - do you know a means to get a blank line *after* the prompt?

Comment: That seems like a weird request. You could print a screen control code to save the cursor position, print an empty line, and return to the saved position, but then of course the empty line will be overwritten by subsequent output.

Comment: Mmmaybe you could then also bind newline to a sequence which prints an additional newline to the terminal before executing the invoked command. Hmm. But who would want that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bash 4.4 and you want a blank line *after* your prompt, you could set the `PS0` prompt to a newline:

```
PS0="\n"
```

Now, this will be inserted every time you run a command:

```
$ echo "Hello"

Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Wondering this too, I've looked at the menu options in Terminal & most of the control characters one can type in and nothing does this on a keystroke. You can however enter an `echo` command, it alone to leave a single blank line below it before the next prompt. `echo \n` will add an extra blank line to that, `echo \n\n` to do 2 extra, ie. 3 blank lines, etc. (you can also do `echo;echo;echo` getting the same effect)

You can create a shell alias like `alias b='echo;echo'` (i couldn't seem to get the \n notation to work in a alias), then entering `b` on a prompt will leave a double-blank line, not bad. Then you gotta figure out how to save aliases in your `.profile` script.

I tried making an alias for the command `' '` ie. space character, which I though you could type like `\` (hmm, stack overflow not formatting this well, that's backslash followed by a space, then return to execute it), but the `bash` shell doesn't seem to allow an alias with that name. It probably wouldn't allow a function named that either (similar to alias), though I didn't check.

I often use the `fish` shell, and I found that it **does** allow a function with that name! Created with `function ' '; echo \n; end` and indeed it works; at the shell prompt, typing the command `\` (again backslash space) leaves a double blank line.

Cool, but.. I tried saving this function using `funcsave ' '` (how you save functions in `fish`, no messing with startup scripts!) and afterwards the function no longer works :^( This is probably a bug in the fish shell. It's in active development right now though, I think I'll report this as a bug since I would kind of like this to work myself.

One could also send Apple a feature request through their bug reporter for an Insert Blank Line menu/keyboard command in Terminal. If someone pays attention to your request it might be implemented in a year maybe.

Comment: Does anyone know if other terminal programs, like iTerm, have an Insert Blank Line feature?

Comment: To install the fish shell, first get homebrew from http://brew.sh/, then `brew install fish` as mentioned on http://fishshell.com/

Comment: Yes. iTerm2 allows for adding blank lines when pressing the enter/return button. See: https://www.iterm2.com

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to solve exactly the same, and for anyone interested in doing the same, I used what [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) said in his comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19262179/2501304) - I created a `.bash_profile` (see details [here](https://mattmazur.com/2012/01/27/how-to-change-your-default-terminal-prompt-in-mac-os-x-lion/)) with the line `export PS1="\n\n$ "`.

Hopefully that helps someone else too!